# How much of the world can one see in a pensieve that the original owner of the memory did not?

Tags: harry-potter

[This comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96747/would-seeing-a-basilisk-in-a-memory-cause-death/96749#comment221957_96749) raised a question for me

During the Chamber of Secrets while Harry is in Riddle's memory he is described as gliding alongside Riddle, watching whatever Riddle saw (however this not really being the pensieve, riddle might be explicitly directing what Harry could see)

Again, when Harry is in Snape's memory in Order of the Phoenix, it is described that Harry hoped Snape would go out of the exam hall in such a way that his parent's would stay in view, so that he could watch them, because otherwise if Snape went in the wrong direction, he would not see his parent's in the memory either

But then again, in the answer linked in that comment, although the memory is from hokey, when she leaves the room, Harry and Dumbledore do not glide out of the room with her, but instead stay in there and see and hear the events that happened between Riddle and Hepzibah Smith

**What is the extent of the pensieve's power for showing the world not seen by the original owner of the memory?**

Comment: @phantom42 the linked question definitely does not answer the question posed here. I see that question as more of a large scale exploration and this as a small scale exploration.

Comment: I'd suggest tightening up your question then, as you ask "how much of the world can one see?" and "what is the extent of the pensieve's power for showing the world?" You may only want to know about more local exploration, but the question does not reflect that.

Comment: @phantom42 it isn't my question.

Comment: @user13267, I tried to update the question, but it was rejected. Sorry this got closed as I don't think the "duplicate" answers your question.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you giving your time to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are constrained by what the person is actually aware of in the memory.

House Elves seem to be aware of things going on even they aren't in the room, or even in the same house.

Observe how Harry is able to just say "Kreacher" and have him appear in Deathly Hallows. At this time Kreacher would likely still be working at Hogwart's in the kitchens (the last order that Harry gave him) and yet he is instantly aware of his master's call and arrives at 12 Grimmauld Place.

So going into the memory of Hokey might mean that because her attention or awareness was still focused on the room with her master, it allowed them to remain in the room with Tom Riddle and Hepzibah Smith while viewing the memory.

Otherwise, it is a mistake by JKR, who is not infallible.

Comment: How about when Harry is in [Snape's memory](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96747/would-seeing-a-basilisk-in-a-memory-cause-death/96749#comment221706_96749) and sees his father had drawn a picture of a snitch with "LE" written on it.

Comment: @mikeazo I don't know, I guess I'll refer you to the last sentence.